# docker entrypoint : use env variables in a required format

Tags: docker, dockerfile, gunicorn

```
ARG PORT=8004
#start server
EXPOSE ${PORT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8004","wsgi:app" ]
```

I need to use the PORT  to specify it as "0.0.0.0:8004"

what are all the ways I can use PORT=8004 in the following format
"0.0.0.0:8004"

I have been trying

```
ARG PORT=8004
ENV PORT=$PORT
#start server
EXPOSE ${PORT}
ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:${PORT}","wsgi:app" ]
```

but I am getting Error: '${PORT}' is not a valid port number.

Comment: What do you mean by all the ways you can use that? Is this sufficient? `ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:${PORT}","wsgi:app" ]`?

Comment: The port inside the container doesn't need to be configurable; just hard-code 8004 (or your choice of other port number) in the two places it appears.

Answer (score 4):

It's not very clear what you need, but if I understood you correctly
You need to add the `PORT` variable as environment variable since `ARG` are only available during build time.
So if you add like bellow:

```
ENV PORT=$PORT
```

You should be able to use it in the entrypoint.

```
ARG PORT=8004
ENV PORT=$PORT
#start server
EXPOSE ${PORT}

ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:${PORT}","wsgi:app" ]
```

**EDIT**:

As you menttioned in your comment it indeed don't read the variable in `ENTRYPOINT` but if you run it as shell it working fine, I just tested it.

So create script `entrypoint.sh` the name is not set in stone (make sure to give it execute permissions).

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT wsgi:app
```

In the dockerfile:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

P.S. 
Dose are seperated issues

1. is with `ARG` only interpreted in build time.
2. `ENTRYPOINT` not recognizing environment variables.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your answer before I posted! Is there a reason for having a separate `ENV` variable instead of using the `ARG` variable directly? edit: you edited the post and clarified this!

Comment: Error: '${PORT}' is not a valid port number.
getting this error @Shmuel
getting this error when I run the container

Comment: @KSHARSHA This is same symptom but diffrent issue, anyway i updated my answer with a way to solve `Error: '${PORT}' ` as well.

Comment: @Shmuel
having issue with passing port value .
so currently  when I build a docker image and I pass the port value 8005  during build and later run it with 8005  the container  runs with port 8005 .
Create docker image:
 
  docker build -t test:1.0 . --build-arg PORT=8005 
 
 Run docker container:
 
  docker run -p 8005:8005 -d test:1.0
  
BUT I need  to pass the port during RUN not during build (this is not working and its taking 8004)  
Create docker image:
 
  docker build -t test:1.0 . 
 
 Run:
  docker run -p 8004:8004 -d test:1.0 -e PORT=8004 
how to pass during run?

Comment: I just tested it again with `docker run` and it is working fine,

Comment: It is a little hard to understood the issue in the comments like this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66339588/docker-set-custom-port-as-env-variables-during-runtime-rather-than-build

I posted a new one as this different from original question @Shmuel

Comment: Consider accsepting this answer if it was helpfull for you.