# Docker :set custom port as env variables during runtime rather than build

Tags: docker

docker file

```
FROM flask:1.0

COPY ./ /app
WORKDIR /app

# install commands
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y sudo
#RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get update
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y curl

#installing sql server odbc
RUN DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get install -y apt-utils



#install python stuff
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
ENTRYPOINT [ "python3" ]

#start server

ARG PORT=8004
ENV PORT=$PORT
#start server
EXPOSE ${PORT}

# RUN chmod +x src/entrypoint.sh 
RUN chmod +x entrypoint.sh
# ENTRYPOINT [ "gunicorn", "-w", "4", "-b", "0.0.0.0:8004", "--chdir", "src", "wsgi:app" ]
ENTRYPOINT ["./entrypoint.sh"]
```

entrypoint file

```
#!/bin/sh
gunicorn -w 4 -b 0.0.0.0:$PORT --chdir src wsgi:app
```

so currently when I build a docker image and I pass the port value 8005 during build and later run it with 8005 the container runs with port 8005 .

```
Create docker image:
 docker build -t test:1.0 . --build-arg PORT=8005 
Run docker container: docker run -p 8005:8005 -d test:1.0
```

BUT I need to pass the port during RUN not during build (this is not working and its taking 8004)

```
Create docker image: 
docker build -t test:1.0 . 
Run: docker run -p 8005:8005 -d test:1.0 -e PORT=8005
```

Comment: Why bother? You can select a host port (the lefthand side of the `-p` argument) of your choice indepdent of what port the service in the container is listening on. So you can do `-p 8004:8005` to expose the service on port 8004 on the host, or `-p 1234:8005` to expose the service on port 1234 on the host, etc. Just leaving the container configuration itself static.

Comment: do I have to change anything in docker file?
@larsks
are you saying below works?
docker run -p 8004:8005 -d test:1.0

Comment: I am saying you don't need to change the container configuration in order to expose the service on a host port of your choice. Something like what you posted in your comment should work just fine, assuming your service is listening on port 8005 in the container.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you not give the `-e port` to the `docker run` command but to the whatever running in the container.

The following should work,.

```
docker run -p 8005:8005 -d -e PORT=8005 test:1.0
```

For example if you run :

```
docker run -p 8005:8005 -d -e PORT=8005 test:1.0 ls
```

It will output the content of the workdir inside the container.